# fputcsv doesn't work with a specific file

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fputcsv, fclose

I have a PHP function who write line into 3 different CSV files :

```
    if ($fonction == 1)
    {
        $handle = fopen("service_trames_acces.csv", "a");
        $ligne = array($fonction,$groupe,$zone,$no_lecteur,$no_carte, date("d/m/Y"),$date_courante2,$chrono[$no_chrono]['NO_CHRONO'],$cod_typ_acces,$statut,$codeErreur,0);
        fputcsv($handle,$ligne);
        fclose($handle);
    }

    if($fonction == 2)
    {

        $handle = fopen("service_trames_monet.csv", "a");
        $ligne = array($fonction,$groupe,$zone,$no_lecteur,$no_carte,date("d/m/Y"),$date_courante2,$chrono[$no_chrono]['NO_CHRONO'],$cod_typ_monet,$statut,1,$val_nbu_auto,$val_nbu_prec,$codeErreur,0);
        fputcsv($handle,$ligne);
        fclose($handle);
    }
    if($fonction == 3)
    {

        $handle = fopen("service_trames_badg.csv", "a");
        $ligne = array($fonction,$groupe,$zone,$no_lecteur,$no_carte,date("d/m/Y"),$date_courante2,$chrono[$no_chrono]['NO_CHRONO'],self::$entree_sortie,$statut,$codeErreur,0,0);
        fputcsv($handle,$ligne);
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

The third if never write into the file.

- fopen returns a ressource id
- fputcsv returns the lenght of the written line

But the file is always empty. I doesn't have this issue on production server, only in test and if I use any other file name it works.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: do you have permission to write file?

Comment: Test this example http://php.net/manual/es/function.fputcsv.php#refsect1-function.fputcsv-examples but your file..

Comment: var_dump($ligne) ¿?

Answer (score -1):

The commented Snippet below might help. It is very necessary to ensure you have «Write Permission» on the File you intend to write to as well as the containing Folder. The Snippet below ensures that you have this Permission but only on the level of the File. It uses `chmod()` to achieve that purpose. For the directory containing the File, it is up to you to figure out a way to give do it efficiently.

```
<?php 


    // CREATE AN ARRAY TO MAP $fonction TO SPECIFIC FILES
    $loadableFiles  = [
        1   => "service_trames_acces.csv",
        2   => "service_trames_monet.csv",
        3   => "service_trames_badg.csv",
    ];

    // OPEN A STREAM, AUTOMATICALLY LOADING THE NECESSARY FILE 
    // BASED ON THE VALUE OF $fonction
    $handle         = fopen($loadableFiles[$fonction]);

    // CREATE A BASE ARRAY TO HOLD ALL ENTRIES SHARED ACROSS ALL CASES
    $shared         = [ $fonction, $groupe, $zone, $no_lecteur, 
                        $no_carte, date("d/m/Y"),  $date_courante2, 
                        $chrono[$no_chrono]['NO_CHRONO'] ];

    // INITIALIZE $ligne TO NULL
    $ligne          = null;

    // USING THE VALUE OF $fonction BUILD THE $ligne ARRAY
    switch($fonction){
        case 1;
            $ligne  = [ $cod_typ_acces, $statut, $codeErreur, 0];
            break;
        case 2;
            $ligne  = [ $cod_typ_monet, $statut, 1,  $val_nbu_auto,
                        $val_nbu_prec,  $codeErreur, 0];
            break;
        case 3;
            $ligne  = [ self::$entree_sortie, $statut, $codeErreur, 0, 0];
            break;
    }

    // IF WE HAVE SOME DATA IN THE $ligne ARRAY, THEN WE PROCESS AND SAVE THE CSV
    // TO BE SURE WE HAVE "WRITE-PERMISSION" ON THE FILE; 
    // WE EXPLICITLY GIVE THE PERMISSION AGAIN
    if($ligne) {
        // MERGE $shared WITH $ligne
        $ligne      = array_merge($shared, $ligne);

        // GIVE READ/WRITE PERMISSIONS TO THE FILE OWNER (@LEAST)...
        chmod($loadableFiles[$fonction], 0644);

        // TRY SAVING THE FILE...
        // DUMP THE ERROR MESSAGE ON FAILURE... 
        // YOU MIGHT AS WELL THROW AN EXCEPTION...
        try{                
            fputcsv($handle, $ligne);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    // CLOSE THE STREAM
    fclose($handle);
```